# Android ListView ellipsize wide column content

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a ListView that shows 2 columns per row.  I don't have any specific column layout XML so Android is determining it for me.  If the text in the 1st column is too wide then bad things happen to the layout of the 2nd column.  Ideally I want Android to ellipsize the text in the 1st column at a sensible width and/or restrict the 1st column's width to 80% of the total displayable width.  Can I do this in code?

Am happy to ellipsize the column 1 text itself manually when setting up the ListView if that's simple but it would have to cope with orientation changes (because in landscape the column 1 text would not be so wide as to have to ellipsize).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the width of your textviews to a specific width, ie, 50dp instead of wrap_content.
Then set ellipsize to true.
The rest should take care of itself.

Comment: Thanks, this led me in the right direction.  I went with layout_width="0dp" and layout_weight=80/20.  Also had to change from RelativeLayout to LinearLayout.

Comment: No problem. I recommend you find another way to get the layout to behave nicely without using weights. Weights are unstable and processing intensive, but if you're app is relatively lightweight, you're free to use it.

Comment: If you want percentages, such as 80/20 split, then are there other ways to accomplish this?  I wouldn't want to hard-code, for example, 40dp and 10dp because that surely wouldn't be correct for all screen sizes/orientations.

Comment: You can get the screen height and width in pixels in java by doing this:


Display d = ((android.view.WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
int screenWidth = d.getWidth();

That's what I personally use for all of my GUI needs